# quick launch for to open a newform.aspx with modal dialog box

Tags: quick-launch

I am working on Sharepoint 2013..I would like to use the quick launch for to open a newform.aspx with modal dialog box and all tests i realized don't work.

Answer (score 0):

Go to : **List Settings > Advanced Settings > Launch forms in a dialog? > Yes**

**Screenshot:**

[image]

Comment: already  done but don't work

Comment: which type of list are you using ?

Comment: Custom List with content type

Comment: this script editor works on the page, but i want launch this modal dialog box since the quick launch
<script>
function openDialog(pageUrl) { 
var options = {
    url: pageUrl,
    title: 'Title of the Dialog',
    allowMaximize: false,
    showClose: true,
    width: 500,
    height: 500
};
SP.SOD.execute('sp.ui.dialog.js', 'SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog', options);       
}

</script> 
<a href="#" onclick="openDialog('https://dxcportal.sharepoint.com/sites/bmsDXCITServices/Knowledge/Lists/Document%20List/NewForm.aspx');">New Form</a